# Cannot use pipenv to install django. PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Pipfile'

Tags: python, django, pipenv

Currently trying to install django 2.1 in my command prompt through pipenv command. However there's an error where it says Pipfile access denied.

```
    C:\windows\system32>pipenv install django==2.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py",
 line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py",
 line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pipenv
.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packa
ges\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 764, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packa
ges\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packa
ges\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packa
ges\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packa
ges\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packa
ges\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packa
ges\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packa
ges\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 17, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packa
ges\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 235, in install
    retcode = do_install(
  File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packa
ges\pipenv\core.py", line 1734, in do_install
    ensure_project(
  File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packa
ges\pipenv\core.py", line 567, in ensure_project
    project.touch_pipfile()
  File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packa
ges\pipenv\project.py", line 677, in touch_pipfile
    with open("Pipfile", "a"):
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Pipfile'
```

I'm new. I'm in the process of learning on how to build a website.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the command prompt as an administrator. If you don't know how to do this, a shortcut is to do `WIN + x` and then press `A` when a menu shows.